# python apply relativedelta to a column of dates

Tags: python, datetime, vectorization

below is my df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2014-03-27', '2014-03-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04', '2014-04-07','2014-04-08', '2014-04-09'],

})
```

I can create a column with another date which is two months prior to the date on the row.

```
df['Date1'] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) + relativedelta(months=-2))
```

is there a much faster way to perform that same task (vectorization for instance)?my original df is really huge 30-40k rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas datetime functions vectorized

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) - pd.DateOffset(months=2)
df
```

Out:

```
         Date      Date1
0  2014-03-27 2014-01-27
1  2014-03-28 2014-01-28
2  2014-03-31 2014-01-31
3  2014-04-01 2014-02-01
4  2014-04-02 2014-02-02
5  2014-04-03 2014-02-03
6  2014-04-04 2014-02-04
7  2014-04-07 2014-02-07
8  2014-04-08 2014-02-08
9  2014-04-09 2014-02-09
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but small suggestion `pd.to_datetime(df.Date) + pd.DateOffset(months=-2)`. This enable month to be passed as varible.

Comment: @Vishnudev - To me the intention would be less clear. But please post it as your own answer and let the voting system decide.

Comment: Let peace be upon us!!! Liked both your answers fellas ! appreciate your help again

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny This intention is to add a dateoffset, which can be negative or positive offset. Helps to keep it generic. I did not want to post it as an answer as it is just a small change. Hence, left a comment on your answer.